# Hard disk read error

Tags: hard-drive

I have some old (8 years) hdd, Maxtor 40Gb (i think that full model number is not important here). Suddenly, i can't read some files from it. Using chkdsk, after LONG scan i realised i have some 380 kb in bad sectors, but there's about 10 GB of data i can't read! When chkdsk starts scanning everything goes nice, SILENT and fast until 33%. Then, scanning gets A LOT slower, and some wired, suptile and quite silent "ping" started appearing from my disk on every second. Yes! When i try to read some corrupted data, hdd started doing "bing....0.5-1 second pause....bing....0.5-1 sec pause...bing" and after a while read error pops out.

Can enyone tell me what to do? I have copied all files i could, but is there ANY way to save other 10 GBs i got jailed there? What's that silent "ping" sound? Is it my hdd's bell of death? Is there any hope for saving rest of my 10Gb without spending "10Gb" od money?

Comment: Your drive is dying. Consult a data recovery company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the drive is on it's last legs.

From the sounds you are talking about, I'm guessing the data is now unrecoverable using your existing drive and I would have no faith in the drive holding any of the data that currently appears fine.

Your only hope is to send the drive off to a data recovery specialist, but they aren't cheap.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to use some "low level fancy" software to salvage as much as possible (i read it could take up to 10 hours of work, depending of hdd state). i know that Maxtor doesn't exist anymore, but can you recommend me somemanuf. that is known for realibility? I'm interested in plain desktop hdd. Seagate? Samsung? WD?